# Recursive square root loop in python with a epsilon of .0001

Tags: python, loops, square-root

I need help with a square root calculator.
 The directions are as follows:

"You need to implement the Babylonian Method for computing square roots. Based on that core functionality, you are to write an interactive program that:

Prompts the user to enter an integer value above zero.
Checks to ensure that the value is indeed above zero. If not, the program displays an error message and asks for the input again.
Computes the square root of the value using the Babylonian Method outlined above.
Displays the square root to the user formatted to show exactly 3 decimal places (no more than 3, and no less than 3)."

I can't use the sqrt function. I'm getting really close but can't quite get to the right loop. Here's what I have so far

```
# Ask user if they would like to calculate a square root for a single number or range.
single = input("Enter 'single' or 'range' to solve for a single square root or a range of values, respectively: ")

# Set error message to let the user know 'range' calculation are not currently available.
if single == 'single' or 'Single':

    # Ask user to enter a positive integer.
    number = int(input("Enter a positive integer value: "))

    # Set error message asking for valid number if user enters something other than a positive integer.
    while number < 0:
        print("Please enter a valid number.")
    else:
        # Choose epsilon
        epsilon = .0001

        # Choose estimate for the square root of x
        estimate = 4

        # Evaluate the estimate
        while number - estimate > epsilon:
            # Calculate the square root using the Babylonian Method.
            estimate = (number + 1.0) / 2.0
            second_estimate = (estimate + number / estimate) / 2.0

            # Print the users selected value and its square root.
            print("Value", "   ", "Square Root")
            print(" ", number, "        ", format(second_estimate, '.3f'))
else:
    # Tell user 'range' calculation are not currently available.
    print("That function is not currently available.")
```

Comment: `single == 'single' or 'Single'` will always return `True` because the string `'Single'` will act as `True`. Try the following to fix that: `if single.lower()=='single':` that way you don't have to worry about case

Comment: Thank you Patrick! Any thoughts on my equation loop? It winds up being a infinite loop where the square root of 9 (for example) is 3.400 without the recursion getting the actual square root.

Comment: You are never updating `number`. Therefore, `estimate` will never change. For your example, I get `estimate = 5.0, number-estimate=4.0` forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for the while loop is wrong. `number` is `9` and `estimate` goes to `3`. So you have to check `number - estimate*estimate` (take the absolute value because estimate converges to `3` from above for a starting value of `4`). You dont need the first estimate according to [Babylonian method on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method).
Also estimate is always `5` in your code. (`estimate = (number + 1.0) / 2.0` where `number` is always `9`)

```
number = 9
epsilon = .0001
estimate = 4
while abs(number - estimate*estimate) > epsilon:
    estimate = (estimate + number/estimate) / 2.0
    print("Value", "   ", "Square Root")
    print(" ", number, "        ", format(estimate, '.4f'))
```

Result:

```
Value     Square Root
  9          3.1250
Value     Square Root
  9          3.0025
Value     Square Root
  9          3.0000
```

Comment: Oh ya! I see it now. This is perfect. Thanks Jonas!